# How to run an independent PHP script in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel and PHP, so I apologize if something similar is asked before which I couldn't find as per my needs. I have an independent PHP script in public folder:

```
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASS','');
define('DB_NAME','fyp');
define('API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AAAAk4V5b8k:APA91bFUo5crCI-gmfhlB9znAWpxdy9bdvA-29VBgLdRmQtYvjNuUe4xi7lkmyAmTOuhuCaaSphaGTvULTq6oREJEUwNNRBW9AKiadl9zzjbXFnEwINlfJzGFIpZojWim2cTT2D7rKJz');
//$registrationIds = 'f4tul16ETjK6wR64Nix7HO:APA91bGPa4ijApEp_vrDcAr-NEzUU-WcovjLhpxtwSiNv94aZ-aOMVek0AbTHNFHCmwZrXOzeqocFglWOlABWcjcDXnDdmh2qEsIgh0X7MkXcN_YD6qBREP5QyS1WlGn27qGiyYTdpoV';

$id = $_POST['id'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$case_id = $_POST['case_id'];
```

What I want is to pass the values to this script and execute when I press a button on my page e.g.
When I press save, the following function in the controller executes:

```
public function storedetail(Request $req, $id) 
{   
    $detail = Detail::firstOrNew(['case_id' =>  $id,]);       
    $detail->lawyerName = $req->input('lawyerName');
    $detail->event = $req->input('proc_type');
    $detail->room = $req->input('room');
    $detail->eventDate = $req->input('date');   
    $detail->status = 1;
    // $data = Cases::find($id);
    $detail->case_id = $id; 
    // $data->details()->save($detail);
    $detail->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

What is the simplest way to pass the id, status and case_id to the PHP script and execute it?

Comment: create helper file and call that function where ever required! and add it to composer.json
https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers

Answer (score 0):

As per I understand you just need to pass data from laravel controller to separate php file.

just pass all the parameters to the specific file path.

ex : xyz.com/public/phpfile.php?id=123&status=abc&case_id=45